# ANDROID - MapView

Tags: android, bitmap, zooming, pan, android-canvas

Can some one please help me few things regarding mapview im trying to build.
I have a renderer that takes canvas and draws a bitmap in it.
I have created a view and in constructor i create:

```
bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(windowWidth, windowHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
drawable = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
this.Render();
```

In onDraw method i have this:

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
canvas.save();
canvas.translate(mPosX, mPosY);
canvas.scale(mScaleFactor, mScaleFactor);
drawable.draw(canvas);
canvas.restore();
```

Now i would like to implement pan and zoom (currently im working without saved tiles)
Here is my onTouch:

mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

```
final int action = ev.getAction();
switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
    this.hasPanned = false;
    final float x = ev.getX();
    final float y = ev.getY();

    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;
    mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
    final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
    final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
    final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

    if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
        final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
        final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

        mPosX += dx;
        mPosY += dy;

        invalidate();
    }

    mLastTouchX = x;
    mLastTouchY = y;

    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    if (this.mDownTouchX != this.mLastTouchX && this.mDownTouchY != mLastTouchY)
        this.hasPanned = true;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
    mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
    break;
}

case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
    final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
            >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
    final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
    if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
        final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
        mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
        mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
        mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
    }
    break;
}
}
return true;
```

Here is what i would like and problems i have:

1. When i pan i would like to calculate distance in pixels so i can tell my renderer when it renders the image again. How is this achieved? By remembering coordinates on ACTION_DOWN and comparing with new coordinates in ACTION_UP ?
2. When pan is complete (and image is re-rendered) i would like to set the canvas(image) back to its original position. Currently it stays paned (because of canvas.translate?)
3. How do i handle zoom gestures? With this code when doing a zoom-out with my fingers the image is "dragged" towards top left corner ...

Im new in android (and java) so any help is preciated.

Comment: can some one please just explain, why when i do pinch zoom the image is glued to top left corner?

Comment: Not quite sure how this relates to `MapView` ... can you elaborate on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your zoom code zooms the Canvas but doesn't move it correctly, I suspect you are calling the wrong Canvas.scale() method. The method you are using seems to be -

```
scale(float sx, float sy)
```

and I think you need to use -

```
scale(float sx, float sy, float px, float py)
```

sx & sy are obviously the x & y scale factors (I normally set them to the same value). px & py are the centre points for the Zoom operation, e.g. the mid point between the MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN and MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN event coordinates.

In my MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN handler I call -

```
midPoint(mid, event);
```

mid is defined as -

```
private PointF mid = new PointF();
```

and the midPoint function is -

```
private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) 
{
   float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
   float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
   point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
}
```

so in my MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE handler I would call -

```
Canvas.scale(sx, sy, mid.x, mid.y);
```

Comment: thanx for the anwser dave! Can you please advice me with additional problem. I have a map on screen. I know the center point. When i perform pinch zoom i know the midpoint. The image gets streched or shrinked and the center poin moves by the size of the midpoint and the finger wich is further away from midpoint towards or away from midpoint. That means i would have to calculate the center based on the zoom gesture. I hope you understand what i mean. I checked google maps for android and they are keeping the center point wich is wrong... Any suggestions?

Comment: I think you are having problems with the ZOOM affecting the X,Y co-ordinates of the touch event. What you need to do is use an INVERTED matrix to map the event X,Y points in reverse, e.g. - `float[] pts = new float[2];
    pts[0] = event.getX();
    pts[1] = event.getY();
    Matrix invertedMatrix = new Matrix();
    transMatrix.invert(invertedMatrix);
    invertedMatrix.mapPoints(pts);
                         int invX = pts[0];
                         int invY = pts[1];`
and then use the transformed X,Y to determine your real midpoint.

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, in the ACTION_DOWN just do

```
PontF downAt = new PointF(event.getX(), event.getY());
```

and in ACTION_UP calculate the difference between pixels.

2) The MapView works differently to an ImageView. For a MapView you would use

```
mapView.getController().animateTo(GeoPoint);
```

but I think you really want to subclass from an ImageView and override the onDraw(Canvas canvas) method for direct access to the Canvas. Then use a Matrix to handle translation & zooming, e.g.

```
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);
Matrix imageMatrix = new Matrix();
imageMatrix.postTranslate(xMove, yMove);
imageMatrix.postScale(scaleX, scaleY, midX, midY);
imageView.setImageMatrix(imageMatrix);
```

3) To handle ZOOM gestures, you need to handle the ACTION_POINTER_DOWN, ACTION_MOVE & ACTION_POINTER_UP events. There is a really good tutorial here -
[How to use Multi-touch in Android](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/how-to-use-multi-touch-in-android-2/1747)

Be careful when you ZOOM an imageView, any subsequent drawing on it needs the X,Y co-ordinates also scaled, use the Matrix mapPoints(Pts) method to do this.

Comment: the code i posted (class MyMapView) extends View. I tried using the code from that sample but i cant get it to work on my class that extends view. Zooming with my code works, its just that the image is "glued" to the upper left corner when performing the zoom. After the zoom (pinch gesture) is released i will render the canvas again. Also ... how do i implement double tap and two button tap in my code? The view does not have the methods so i guess i need to implement gesturedetector? Am i going in the right direction here?

Comment: Thats a seperate question to the one you posted. Please post a seperate question if you want answers to tap events.